# Rspec Rails controller submit form params URI encoded rather than hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller

I'm testing a controller, and when I submit the form data some of it is coming into the controller as a string, rather than the hash I am expecting.

```
def send_request(params={})
  patch :update, params.merge(:id => @company.id)
end

describe 'should_receive' do
  let(:test_params) do
    {
      "utf8"=>"✓",
      "_method"=>"patch",
      "button"=>"",
      "company"=>
      { "label_ids"=>[""],
        "customer_users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"3", "is_primary"=>"true"}},
        "baselines_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"label_ids"=>[""], "benchmark_ids"=>[""], "id"=>"1"}}},
      "action"=>"update",
      "controller"=>"admin/companies",
    }
  end

  after(:each) do
    send_request(test_params)
  end

  it { @company.should_receive(:update).with(test_params).and_return(true) }
```

The error when the test is run:

```
 Failure/Error: patch :update, params.merge(:id => @company.id)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `has_key?' for "baselines_attributes%5Bsite_url%5D=site_url":String
```

the params just before the failure:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "button"=>"",
 "company"=>
  "baselines_attributes%5B0%5D%5Bbenchmark_ids%5D%5B%5D=&baselines_attributes%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=1&baselines_attributes%5B0%5D%5Blabel_ids%5D%5B%5D=&customer_users_attributes%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=3&customer_users_attributes%5B0%5D%5Bis_primary%5D=true&label_ids%5B%5D=",
 "action"=>"update",
 "controller"=>"admin/companies",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

The params at the same location when the form is submitted via a browser:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "button"=>"",
 "company"=>
  {"label_ids"=>[""],
   "customer_users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"3",
     "is_primary"=>"true"}},
   "baselines_attributes"=>{
     "0"=>{"label_ids"=>[""], "benchmark_ids"=>[""], "id"=>"1"}}},
 "action"=>"update",
 "controller"=>"admin/companies",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

in the test everything in params[:company] is a URI encoded string, whereas in the real code it comes in properly as a hash.

How can I get the test data to be properly handled?

**Update**

Ruby 2.2.0

Relevant gems:

- rails (4.0.13)
- rspec-core (2.14.8)
- nested_form (0.3.2)

Comment: Can you post your markup?  Are you using `simple_form`?

Comment: I think posting the markup would be a distraction, but I will add details about the gems / versions. The code works properly, it is the test that is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use FactoryGirl to build attributes?

Comment: We use FactoryGirl elsewhere, but I didn't write the test. My guess is the author is just testing simple functionality and doesn't want to build up a full suite of objects to test this. How would FactoryGirl help here?

Comment: This question would be better as a comment and seems unrelated to solving the OP's problem